# Array of dynamic array of queue in SV

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

I'm trying to create an array(10 elements) of dynamic array(5 elements) of a queue(of size 3). 
I'm doing -

```
typedef int q[$:2];
typedef q dyn_arr;
dyn_arr arr_dyn_arr[][5]= new[10];
```

I'm not sure whether it's the right way.

Comment: `[$:2]` says the maximum size of the queue is three elements - it does not create elements. And if you have a two dimensional array of 5X3, where is the number 10 coming from?

Comment: I need 10 elements for the array. Doesn't the statement  dyn_arr arr_dyn_arr[][5]= new[10]; create 10x5 ?

Comment: Your `typedef q dyn_arr` does not do anything except rename q to dyn_array. The variable you are declaring is a 3-dimensional array as if you had declared `int arr_dyn_arr [][5][$:2];`  So your `new[10]` creates a 10x5 array of empty queues.

Comment: @dave_59,  got it now. Thanks for the explanation. Will remove the extra statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `typedef q dyn_arr;` does not do anything except alias `q` to `dyn_array`. The variable you are declaring is a 3-dimensional array as if you had declared

```
int arr_dyn_arr [][5][$:2];
```

So your `new[10]` creates a 10x5 array of empty queues